# overlay a sticky div over a normal div without using absolute

Tags: html, css

How do I position a sticky div on top of a regular div?

My requirements are that the first `div` of the page should be covering `100%` of `width` and `height`. After scrolling the menu should be `sticky` on `top`. What I have managed to achieve so far is that the menu stays `sticky`, but it should be on `top` of of the blue `div`, not after it. Is this possible to do?

```css
#container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#menu {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 10; 
  top: 0px;
}

#content {
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#menu { 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.